# PDO ODBC: Invalid string or buffer length

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, unixodbc

We are using a PDO to connect to a MSSQL Server using the DSN:

```
odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};;Server=*.*.*.*;Database=whatever;
```

When trying to `execute()` an `INSERT` statement we are getting the following error message:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[HY090]: Invalid string or buffer length: 0 [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Invalid string or buffer length (SQLExecute[0] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.5.18/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message appears to be a pretty default error message that can mean a wealth of different things.

In our case it was simply that a parameter had been mentioned in the prepared statement but hadn't been bound.  Grrrrr!

Comment: you should also add pertinent code so that when people encounters the same problem and stumble upon this question, they'll know also.

Comment: Rob, may you please add your code, as I am facing same issue.

Comment: The specifics of my actual code are rather irrelevant hence their omission. The issue is the poor error messages being returned by the driver. I would double check that all of the parameters that you have included in your query are then bound before executing the query.

Comment: I just encountered this error message because my SQL script started with a new line. Removing the empty line resolved it. Like @RobForrest said this seems to be a generic error message though with different underlying causes.